# REST call for ApprovaProcess and ApprovalEntryCriteria not working

Tags: metadata-api, rest, approval-process

I posted a question about this some days ago.

I'm trying to retrieve ApprovalEntryCriteria for an specific ApprovalProcess via metadata REST call:

```
/services/data/v44.0/metadata/salesforce/types/ApprovalProcess/[id]
```

But it's giving me the following error:

**Service not found at: /services/data/v44.0/metadata/salesforce/types/ApprovalProcess/[id]**

What's the proper way to retrieve this information and also entryCriteria for that ApprovalProcess?

Regards

**EDIT:**

RAW response:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Fri, 29 Mar 2019 09:50:21 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536002; includeSubDomains
Public-Key-Pins-Report-Only: pin-sha256="9n0izTnSRF+W4W4JTq51avSXkWhQB8duS2bxVLfzXsY="; pin-sha256="5kJvNEMw0KjrCAu7eXY5HZdvyCS13BbA0VJG1RSP91w="; pin-sha256="njN4rRG+22dNXAi+yb8e3UMypgzPUPHlv4+foULwl1g="; max-age=86400; includeSubDomains; report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/hpkp-report/00D6E0000000eOkm";
Expect-CT: max-age=0; report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/Expect-CT-report/00D6E0000000eOkm";
X-Robots-Tag: none
Cache-Control: no-cache,must-revalidate,max-age=0,no-store,private
Set-Cookie: BrowserId=EwSuJuHRT9itFaNmiovVyg;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Tue, 28-May-2019 09:50:21 GMT;Max-Age=5184000
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Sforce-Limit-Info: api-usage=3023/70751600
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked


[ {
  "errorCode" : "NOT_FOUND",
  "message" : "The requested resource does not exist"
} ]
```

Comment: Is that the actual error you're getting, precisely?

Comment: @sfdcfox I put the wrong endpoint in error display. Fixed. Also added RAW Response for REST call

Comment: see [MetadataAPI doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_working_with_processes.htm) for how to get list of approval processes - I'm not sure entrycriteria is exposed